# When to run and interrupt a django management command

Tags: django, web-applications, rss, django-manage.py

I have a custom django-command that reads and RSS, looks for new feeds and, if any new feed is found, I push it (pusher.com) to my webapp hosted in Heroku (heroku.com). This checking needs to be done as much as possible to be able to get the new feeds as soon as possible, let's say, every second.

The two issues I have are:

- As this app will only be used by a few people(2-3), the command must be run only if any of these people are inside the app so I don't overload server jobs.
- Once the user left the app (may be they just closed it, or they have certain time of inactivity, i.e. not clicking anything), the command must stop checking RSS.

My questions are,

- where should I run the command from? directly from a view, from a signal?
- How could I interrupt such command once the user leaves the app?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [request-finished](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#request-finished) signal. In signal handler you could run [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) task, so user hasn't wait the rss server request end